# Failed to call firebase-admin inside middleware by using Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-admin

I use Next.js 13 with firebase-admin (for server) and firebase (for web). I would like to intercept the request in `middleware`. My implementation is given as follows:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { Logger } from "@/lib/logger";
import { PATHNAME_HOME, PATHNAME_LOGIN } from "./utils/constants";
import { adminAuth } from "./lib/firebase-admin-helper";

const redirectTo = (url: string, request: NextRequest) => {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(url, request.url));
};

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  let isLoggedIn = false;
  let useObj = null;
  const sessionValue = request.cookies.get("session")?.value;
  if (sessionValue) {
    // adminAuth is the auth instance from firebase-admin getAuth(app)
    const result = adminAuth.verifySessionCookie(sessionValue, true);
  }

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === PATHNAME_LOGIN) {
    return isLoggedIn
      ? redirectTo(PATHNAME_HOME, request)
      : NextResponse.next({ request });
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return redirectTo(PATHNAME_LOGIN, request);
  }

  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  const userString = JSON.stringify(useObj);
  requestHeaders.set("user", userString);

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
};
```

The following error is thrown when I execute the code:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'request' in '...\node_modules\retry-request'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingCalls/streaming.js
./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.js
./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/index.js
./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/esm/firestore/index.js
./src/lib/firebase-admin-helper.ts
```

I already try to find solutions from the official firebase documentation and the official Next.js documentation. Just like to know how to use firebase-admin directly in the middleware.